# How to use mod_proxy and change the application path?

Tags: apache, tomcat, apache2, tomcat7, mod-proxy

Imagine you want to enable access to your **manager** Tomcat app through Apache.The basic approach would be:

```
ProxyPass /manager ajp://localhost:8009/manager
ProxyPassReverse /manager ajp://localhost:8009/manager
```

And this is working as expected, by access `http://yourdomain/manager`.
However, things do not work if you also want to change the name. Imagine you want to access it through `http://yourdomain/foo`.

```
ProxyPass /foo ajp://localhost:8009/manager
ProxyPassReverse /foo ajp://localhost:8009/manager
```

When you access foo the address bar will change to `http://yourdomain/manager` and display a 404: The requested URL /manager/ was not found on this server.

I've tried the proxy_html code bellow, but with the same results:

```
ProxyPass /foo ajp://localhost:8009/manager
ProxyPassReverse /foo ajp://localhost:8009/manager
SetOutputFilter proxy-html
ProxyHTMLURLMap ^/manager(.*)$ /foo/$1 R
```

I am using version 3.0.1 of mod_proxy_html, hence not having defined "ProxyHTMLEnable On" (which I believe is new in 3.1).
**What is missing or badly defined?** 
(note: I believe you can also do it with a rewrite rule, but this would probably be simpler)

Comment: Any chance you are willing to simply change the name of the manager app within Tomcat? That seems to be a simpler solution.

Comment: Agree 100%. Consider the overhead of mod_proxy_html processing every page and ask yourself whether you really want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will probably go via that route. However, I would still like to know the answer to this question. Mainly because that would enable me to have an interesting possibility: ProxyPasss / ajp://localhost:8009/bar - ie, make application bar be the root application of that domain.